# Create Fixed-Length Vector from List

Tags: haskell

In this blog post https://blog.jle.im/entry/fixed-length-vector-types-in-haskell.html the author creates a `Vec n a`  which is a dependent type vector. One of the functions that creates is `withVec :: [a] -> (forall n. Sing n -> Vec n a -> r) -> r` that creates an intermediate vector from a list and applies a function on it. Is there a way to supply an id-like function to `withVec` in order to extract the intermediate vector? In the comments of this post it creates a `sum :: Sing n -> Vec n Int -> Int` function but any attempt to create a function that it's result is of type `Vec n a` has failed. Also in this https://hackage.haskell.org/package/type-combinators-0.2.4.3/docs/Data-Type-Vector.html package there is no a `fromList` function that will create a `Vec n a` from a list. Why is this? Is there a reason that we cannot create a compile-time checked `fromList` function that will create the appropriate `Vec a n` from a list of length n? I have tried and succeed to create a `fromList` function but it checks the proper length at runtime not at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to supply an id-like function to `withVec` in order to extract the intermediate vector?

No, the type of `withVec` is carefully crafted precisely to *prevent* that.

Side note: in the libraries, this "trick" is mostly known to be used in the type of `runST` for the safety of the `ST s` monad.

> any attempt to create a function that it's result is of type `Vec n a` has failed.

Indeed, that's impossible by design.

> there is no `fromList` function that will create a `Vec n a` from a list. Why is this? Is there a reason that we cannot create a compile-time checked `fromList` function that will create the appropriate `Vec a n` from a list of length n?

It might not be obvious at first, but that's not realistically feasible.

Suppose we did have such a `fromList`. What would its type be? Let's guess:

```
fromList :: [a] -> Vec n a
```

But this actually means

```
fromList :: forall a n . [a] -> Vec n a
```

so it claims to be able to convert any list to any vector *of any length*. That can't be sound.

The issue is that the `forall n` part means that the *caller* of `fromList` gets to choose `n`. But in this way there's no guarantee that `n` is the length of the input list, so there's a mismatch.

We could instead try to make `n` chosen by `fromList` and not the caller.
Pretending that Haskell had existential types as a primitive, we would get

```
fromList :: [a] -> exists n . Vec n a    -- pseudo-Haskell
```

However, this has two consequences.

First, `exists n . Vec n a` would be a type for a vector of unknown length, hence essentially isomorphic to `[a]`, making `fromList` not very useful.

Second, we could exploit a known encoding to represent existential types in real Haskell, but that would be

```
fromList :: forall a r . [a] -> (forall n . Vec n a -> r) -> r
```

which is very similar to `withVec`! (Actually `withVec` is more usable than this variant.)

Another alternative would instead be something like

```
fromList :: Sing n -> [a] -> Maybe (Vec n a)
```

Here, the caller has to (statically) predict the length of the (dynamic) list `n`. If it's correct, they get `Just theVector`, otherwise they get `Nothing`. Whether this is useful or not depends on whether we can guess correctly `n` at static time.

Note that this last variant of `fromList` seems to be realizable given `withVec`, as far as I can see.

Finally, in a fully dependently typed language we could write

```
fromList :: (xs :: [a]) -> Vec (length xs) a   -- not Haskell
```

but Haskell does not have true dependent types (since it aims to allow for full type erasure for efficiency).

Answer (score 1):

Why can't a function convert a list to a vector?

```hs
fromList :: [a] -> Vec n a
```

Applied to the empty list this produces a vector of any length `fromList [] :: Vec n a` when the only sensical type is `Vec 0 a`. You can view this is a vector of "some length *n*" where *n* is existential ([proposal](https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/pull/473)). Without dependent types, we don't know.

```hs
fromList :: [a] -> exists n. Vec n a
```

This is identical to `withVec`, which encodes an existential with CPS. The only difference is `Sing n`: the length is retained (not erased) at runtime.

```
withVec :: [a] -> (forall n. Sing n -> Vec n a -> r) -> r
--                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't think there a relevant name for `exists.` has been decided yet. It's possible to encode this as a datatype.

```hs
type SomeVec :: Type -> Type
data SomeVec a where
  SomeVec :: Sing n -> Vec n a -> SomeVec a

fromList :: [a] -> SomeVec a
```

And such existentials are perfect for pattern synonyms which allow you to pattern match on ordinary lists and get a vector back. I also pattern match on the singleton [`Sing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-3.0.2/docs/Data-Singletons.html#v:Sing) to say that we statically know the length *n*.

```hs
{-# Complete AsVec #-}

--                               existential
--                               vvvvvvvvv
pattern AsVec :: forall a. () => forall n. SingI n => Vec n a -> [a]
pattern AsVec vec <- (fromList -> SomeVec Sing vec)
  where AsVec = fromVec
```

```hs
>> case [1..10] of AsVec vec -> show vec
"1 :> (2 :> (3 :> (4 :> (5 :> (6 :> (7 :> (8 :> (9 :> (10 :> VNil)))))))))"
```

For fun work out what happens when the identity continuation is passed to `` (`withVec` \_ -> id) ``.